# Failing to build ape server on centos

Tags: bash, centos5, linux

I'm trying to build an ape server on Centos 5.6 but getting the following message:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient_r
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [modules] Error 1

How can I get it working? I've found libmysqlclient_r.so in /usr/lib64/mysql and /usr/lib/mysql/ are these the files it needs? If so, how can i get ld to see them?

Answer (score 2):

To make this work, you must edit the Makefile in the modules directory. On line 7 change

```
    MYSQL_FLAGS = -L./deps/mysac/ -I./deps/mysac/ -lmysac -lmysqlclient_r
```

to

```
    MYSQL_FLAGS = -L./deps/mysac/ -L/usr/lib64/mysql -I./deps/mysac/ -lmysac -lmysqlclient_r
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install the -devel RPM for MySQL.

To see whether that's available, try:

```
yum provides '*/libmysqlclient_r.so'
```

If for some reason it's not been seen, you can try:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/mysql make
```

Comment: I already have it installed under mysql-devel!

Comment: try the command above to see if it helps.

Comment: no, still the same response